# Where is the AccountController in a dotnetcore React web app?

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, identityserver4

I'm trying to set up a dotnetcore React web app in Visual Studio, with Identity Server, using the built in project template. However, once I've created it, I can't see the AccountController anywhere.

I've seen posts on how to scaffold the different Identity Server views so that they can be modified, so that's not a problem, but I actually want a further event to occur after a user has registered (creating a related DB table record and linking it to the user).

Would this be done by adding to the AccountController method - and if so, where is it? If that's not how it should work anymore, could someone please point me in the right direction? It's been ages since I worked with Identity Server, so I'm feeling a little lost!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You find the IdentityServer **AccountController** as part of the [QuickStart UI](https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/IdentityServer.Quickstart.UI) project.

to add it to an existing project, you can run these two commands:

```
dotnet new -i Duende.IdentityServer.Templates
dotnet new isui
```